# Why won't my Firebase functions deploy from the CLI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to deploy a Firebase Cloud function to an existing Firebase project. The project already has several functions to which I don't have the source code.

So I need to deploy this one new one. So I try the CLI snippet you see below

```
firebase deploy --only functions:nameofthenewfunction
```

(Obviously I'm substituting for the real name of my function. Yes, I've checked the spelling. Yes, the file goes through ESLint with no errors. And yes, the CLI also lists the existing functions in the project, so I know I'm deploying to the "correct" project.)

Any ideas on why this is (not) happening?

The command works, but doesn't deploy the function. I get the message after running it:
    functions: the following filters were specified but do not match any 
    functions in this project: nameofthenewfunction

Comment: If you're having problems deploying with the Firebase CLI, please contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: * have the cli list the function url after deploy?
* have you check the deployment logs in your firebase console?

Comment: Can you share your Cloud Functions code?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, the error message is suggesting to me that your code doesn't actually have a function called "nameofthenewfunction" defined as an export.

Answer (score 0):

Well, smack my a** and call me goofball, turns out the function I was trying to deploy wasn't actually in the "functions" folder of the project. What do you know, when I moved it there, it deployed perfectly. As you were; I'll just go back to VBScript or whatever ;-)